# adding missing dates in mysql data set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query like this....

```
   SELECT CAST(created_at AS DATE) as 'Created_Date', DAYNAME(CAST(created_at AS DATE)) as 'Day', sum(order_type_id=1) as 'Pickup', sum(order_type_id=2) as 'Delivery'
   FROM orders
   WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   AND created_at < curdate()
   AND order_status_id != 3
   group by CAST(created_at AS DATE);
```

which returns some data as below

```
    Date   |      Day     | Pickup | Delivery
-----------------------------------------------
2017-08-08 |    Tuesday   |  02    |    01    
2017-08-09 |   Wednesday  |  01    |    01    
2017-08-10 |    Thursday  |  01    |    00  
2017-08-11 |    Friday    |  01    |    01   
2017-08-13 |    Sunday    |  01    |    00  
2017-08-14 |    Monday    |  01    |    01
```

What I'm trying to do is to get some summery of the delivery orders and pickup orders for past 7 days excluding today.

**My Prob** : if you closely observe above, you'll notice that I dont have an output for 2017-08-12 (Saturday) since there were no operations done in the same date. Any idea how to get these empty dates into my output so I have something like below????

```
    Date   |      Day     | Pickup | Delivery
-----------------------------------------------
2017-08-08 |    Tuesday   |  02    |    01    
2017-08-09 |   Wednesday  |  01    |    01    
2017-08-10 |    Thursday  |  01    |    00  
2017-08-11 |    Friday    |  01    |    01   
2017-08-12 |   Saturday   |  00    |    00  
2017-08-13 |    Sunday    |  01    |    00  
2017-08-14 |    Monday    |  01    |    01
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: is that the only possible option to sort this out??? Coz my backend is bit complicated with ruby and all. if I can sort this out in database layer itself, it is better

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have data on all days (just not the status you want on that date), then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
   select CAST(created_at AS DATE) as Created_Date,
          DAYNAME(CAST(created_at AS DATE)) as Day,
          sum(order_type_id = 1 and order_status_id <> 3) as Pickup,
          sum(order_type_id = 2 and order_status_id <> 3) as Delivery
   from orders
   where created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND created_at < curdate()
   group by CAST(created_at AS DATE);
```

If that is not the case, then you need a table with one row per date that you want.  The simplest method is a calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

You could try right joining your select with something like this.

```
RIGHT JOIN (
select curdate() as `date`    union
select DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 day) as `date` union
select DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 day) as `date` union
select DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 day) as `date` union
select DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 4 day) as `date` union
select DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 day) as `date` union
select DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 day) as `date`
) as dates
```